# Get string out of the long string without any clear search criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

CN=#account,OU=Application Accounts,OU=Admin Accounts,OU=User Accounts,DC=DomainName,DC=local

CN=_OwnerPRD,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Admin Accounts,OU=User Accounts,DC=DomainName,DC=local

I have a lot of values like the above. How can I pull out just Application Accounts in the first example and Service Accounts in the second example? I'm not sure how I can do this with INSTR due to the lack of unique search criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following using [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) and [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql):

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(column_name, CHARINDEX('OU=', column_name), CHARINDEX(',', column_name, CHARINDEX('OU=', column_name)) - CHARINDEX('OU=', column_name)), 'OU=', '') 
FROM table_name
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/14914/0